# Android (Marshmallow) with sdcard fornatted as internal storage, Android profiles are dropped after reboot

Tags: android-6.0-marshmallow, android-account

I'm really would like to find out if the following problem is a bug

- in some specific apps, some of them open source,
- in Android AOSP,
- or in my cell phone's manufacturer's changes to AOSP

Cell phone is a Lenovo C2 (K10a40) with Android 6.0, latest Lenovo patches.

Full disk encryption (FDE) is enabled.

32GB sdcard is formatted as internal storage, using Android's Adoptable Storage option (https://source.android.com/devices/storage/adoptable).

All Apps which allows movement to "internal storage" sdcard are moved to sdcard.

Several Apps,

- Nextcloud Sync client
- XING app (German social network)
- Onleihe (German public library emedia client)

have the 100% REPRODUCIBLE (and very annoying) behaviour, that all login etc. credentials, stored in an Android account, are dropped after rebooting the phone.

This bug does NOT happen if these apps are stored in "real" internal storage, not on sdcard formatted as internal. Which is of course NOT an acceptable solution, as these apps, esp. Nextcloud and Onleihe, are storing large amounts of data locally.

I've opened a bug for Nextcloud already (https://github.com/nextcloud/android/issues/1814), but up to now no solution in sight.

I've found in the Android docs about the to be set by developer attribute "android:installLocation". Which has to be set, if an app should be allowed to be moved to sdcard in "internal storage" mode in general.

Is there anything special an android developer has to take care of when creating Android accounts, which might have been forgotten to be set for these three apps? Any differences in account handling with Android accounts for apps stored on sdcard?

Thanks in advance,
Michael